# InstallShield Suite project - how to abort from secondary window?

Tags: installshield

I have a InstallShield 2023 Suite project and on the Welcome dialog I check if some process is running, if it does I show a secondary window with a message that user should close the process wit 2 buttons to Retry check or Exit.
My problem is how to exit\abort the setup from the secondary window, I have tried these but none of them did the work:

1. Close Window Action with return code IDABORT ( I tried also all rest )
2. Run Suite action ( install script action ) with code abort and return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
3. Run action that should execute .exe file which doesn’t exists just to trigger failure
4. Set active page to InstallationComplete, this work but I don't know how to change the text displayed which says Initializing

I don’t want to use the exit conditions, any ideas ?